# Subversion tag as string in source files

Tags: svn

I would like to know how I get a release tag in SVN as a string. I know that $Id$ keyword is available in SVN, but it does not contain a release tag. I would like to use a release tag as a string in my source code so that I can use it in the header part of a file that my software produces.

Comment: "release"? Are you asking about something like a software version, but based on the path in subversion (i.e. a tag)?

Comment: @crashmstr I meant to say "version-1-0" in /repository_root/tags/version-1-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Tags" in Subversion are nothing more than a naming convention used in your repository's directory structure. There is no "object" in Subversion that corresponds to a tag in the way that you're expecting. You can use Subversion for a decade without tags, and you can call your tags "labels" instead - Subversion neither knows nor cares.

To do what you're describing, you will need to have as part of your build/package process a script which checks where your code came (the repository URL) from and update whatever files that information needs to be in accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I will add a short script in my CMake process in order to get the tag. But do I need to analyze .svn/wc.db to get the tag? Is there any easier way? I would appreciate it if you could give me any hint.

Comment: You should already know where you're checking out/exporting from (otherwise you wouldn't be able to do a build). Or run `svn info` in your working copy.